# JQuery Table Toggle Row issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, toggle, slidetoggle

I have table which is being dynamically created.
I would like to try not to have any more attributes in the table (like an ID field).
It is a multilevel table where all the TableRows should be expandable and collapse on click in any of the TD in each row.

```
$('.fylke_click').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('.fylke').slideToggle(0);
    $('.sted').hide();
});

$('.kom_click').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('.kommune').slideToggle(0);
});
```

See this simplified fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T2Lwn/

So it's basically 3 levels and it is a lot of problems here.
One obvious one is when you are on the second level, which is called "kommune" and if you click on the last TR it removes the "fylke" underneath. As you can see if you click on "MIDTRE GAULDAL"
This is probably because I use `.Parent()` and I need some sort of if check if I am on the last row?

Is it also other problems with this code? Can I specify the click method `class="fylke_click"` and `class="kom_click"` on a more general level?
For example for all `<tr class="fylke">` each TD class will have `class="fylke_click"` and same for `kommunne`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly this may help:

**[Demo Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/T2Lwn/1/)**

Since you said you're going to be dynamically creating this content, I would recommend delegating off of the main table instead of making a click handler for each row. Also, since all of the stuff you want to show / hide are siblings and not nested, things get a bit tricky. You'll need to be specific with your `.nextUntil()` by passing a filter, and I found a `:not()` on the filter was necessary.

Again, since these are all siblings, it's not as easy as hiding the children of the header row, so I set up an "open" class to check if the header was open or not, and hid / showed stuff depending on if it was already open. 
JS:

```
$('.kommune').hide();
$('.sted').hide();

$('.table').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    $this = $(this);

    if( $this.hasClass('fylke') ){
        if ( $this.hasClass('open') ) {
            $this.toggleClass('open').nextUntil('.fylke', 'tr').hide();
        }
        else {
            $this.toggleClass('open').nextUntil('.fylke', 'tr:not(.sted)').toggle();
        }
    }
    else if ( $this.hasClass('kommune') ){
        $this.nextUntil('.kommune', 'tr:not(.fylke)').toggle();
    }
});
```